# JS Tree Context Menu Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

Initially my JS Tree is

```
<div id="jstree">
<ul>
   <li>Name=
      <ul>
         <li>Deepanshu</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If I edit the name field from Deepanshu to some numeric value, on clicking a submit button, a rest api call happens (which essentially returns the same html back with a pop up saying invalid value). In the html that is returned by the rest call, the js tree is the same as it was before hitting the rest call. Now, if I right click on the node Name or the node Deepanshu either to Edit, Delete, Create new node, etc. the context menu doesn’t appear.

Javascript which I am using is

```
<script>
   $(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
     "core" : {
         "check_callback" : true
     },
     "plugins" : [
         "state", "types", "contextmenu"
      ]
   });

   $('#jstree').on('changed_jstree', function (e, data) {
      console.log(data.selected);
   });
});
</script>
```

It would be great if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the html and javascript you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your html filed.. An example usage for html filed**

```
<div id="plugins2" class="demo plugin-demo">
<ul>
    <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>Root node
        <ul>
            <li>Context click me</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**After, create your JSTree**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#plugins2")
        .jstree({
            "core" : {
                'force_text' : true,
                "check_callback" : true
            },
            "plugins" : [ "contextmenu" ]
        });
});
</script>
```

Keep in mind; when you use JSTree be careful for id fields